# Реализация чата, работающего через тор

Tags: python, сокет, tor, сетевое-программирование

Я реализовываю чат на python с использованием библиотеки socket. Я знаю, что есть мессенджеры, работающие через тор(pidgin, например). Можно ли реализовать соединение клиента с сервером через тор? если да, то с помощью чего это сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Для конечного пользователя Tor это просто SOCKS-прокси (обычно на порту 9150), соответственно достаточно просто соединяться через этот прокси (посмотрите [PySocks](https://pypi.org/project/PySocks/) например)

Comment: @andreymal то есть можно просто присоединиться клиентом к серверу через прокси?